# CNOT quantum gate using tensor products

Tags: tensor-products, quantum-mechanics

In textbook, it states that the CNOT gate with the X gate applied on second qubit is
\begin{array}{cccc}
   1&0&0&0\\
   0&1&0&0\\
   0&0&0&1\\
   0&0&1&0
  \end{array}
However, By tensor products, wouldn't it be $I$ $\otimes$ $U_{x}$
, which gives
\begin{array}{cccc}
   0&1&0&0\\
   1&0&0&0\\
   0&0&0&1\\
   0&0&1&0
  \end{array}

Comment: May I ask the title of the book you are reading?

Comment: QM by david mcyintire

Answer (score 3):

The way that we can write controlled-not operation explicitly algebraically with the control on the first qubit is as follows:
$$ \mathit{CNOT} \;=\; \def\ket#1{\lvert #1 \rangle}\def\bra#1{\langle #1 \rvert}\ket{0}\!\bra{0} \!\otimes\! \mathbf 1 \,+\, \ket{1}\!\bra{1} \!\otimes\! \: \sigma_x$$
where $\mathbf 1$ is an identity matrix of $2\times2$ order.

You can now see why it should give the desired answer.

Comment: Thanks that works out. can you explain thought why we cannot switch the order of the tensor products(I know tensor products are generally not commutative), but why does the CNOT operator happen to have the outer proudct on the left side? is there a specific reason?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain what do you mean? If you are interested in writing any unitary gate operation in terms of a matrix, refer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/360720/matrix-representation-of-quantum-gates) question.

Comment: As you stated, tensor products are not commutative. Kronecker products are written in the order the gates are applied.

Comment: BY same logic, if x gate was now acting on first qubit, control on second, then wouldn't it be $$ \mathit{CNOT} \;=\; \def\ket#1{\lvert #1 \rangle}\def\bra#1{\langle #1 \rvert}\ket{0}\!\bra{0} \!\otimes\! \sigma_x \,+\, \ket{1}\!\bra{1} \!\otimes\! \: \mathbf 1$$, which gives incorrect operator matrix?

Comment: Yes, but how is it incorrect? You have changed the control to second qubit and the action on the first will be negated, which is to say you have reversed the control and the operating qubits and the corresponding matric is what you have written.

Comment: Well if you just google the 4x4 operator for this case, the above expression is incorrect. I asked my professor and he said this still acts on 1st qubit as control..     \begin{array}{cccc}
   1&0&0&0\\
   0&X11&0&X12\\
   0&0&1&0\\
   0&X21&0&X22
  \end{array} this is the correct array, for any gate with elements Xij and the control on 2ndqubit, which the above expression fails to give.

Comment: I'm sorry, which expression is incorrect?

Comment: CNOT=|0⟩⟨0|⊗+|1⟩⟨1|⊗1 does not give correct operator for control on bottom, Xgate on top